Nuxt server-side rendering on api requests behind authentication (Laravel)?
I am new to all this SSR stuff and have most experience with just vue3 as a spa + Laravel as backend.  For a new project, I tried starting with a boilerplate : [https://github.com/k2so-dev/laravel-nuxt) for getting basic concepts in place out of the box to play with..
So my case is, I have a site, where I present stuff behind login.
My backend runs Laravel on a different domain than the frontend.
Although it is behind login, nothing is personalized, so I would like some requests done server-side.
But this is where things start going south..
In my boilerplate it seems like there is a plugin "https://github.com/k2so-dev/laravel-nuxt/blob/main/nuxt/plugins/app.ts" that sets the bearer token and baseUrls, security headers and stuff.. Works quite well on the client side..
So I made a store, to fetch som picks:
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import type { BettingPick } from "~/models/BettingPick";
import { setTTL } from "~/utils/date-helper";

export const usePickStore = defineStore({
  id: "pick",
  state: () => ({
    picks: [] as BettingPick[],
    ttl: setTTL(0),
  }),
  getters: {
    getPicks: (state) => {
      return () => {
        const picks = state.picks;
        const ttl = state.ttl;
        if (picks.length > 0 && ttl > new Date()) {
          console.log("yay");
          //Return data if exists and if ttl is valid
          return picks;
        } else {
          //Fetch new data if missing or if ttl is invalid
          console.log("Noo");
          usePickStore()
            .fetchPicks()
            .then((picks) => {
              console.log("hmm");
            })
            .finally(() => {
              return state.picks;
            });
        }
      };
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchPicks() {
      const { data }: any = await useFetch("/betting/picks", { server: true });
      if (data.value) {
        this.picks = data.value.data;
        this.ttl = setTTL(5);
      }
    },
  },
});

And in my component I do this:

<script setup lang="ts">
import { usePickStore } from "~/stores/BettingPickStore";

//const count = await useFetch("betting/picks")

const store = usePickStore();
const { getPicks } = store;
const picks = computed(() => usePickStore().picks);

await callOnce(getPicks);
</script>
<template>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="flex flex-column">
      <template v-for="pick in picks" :key="pick.id">
        <div>{{ pick?.matchup }}</div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


No matter what I do, it does not seem that my backend gets called server-side at all. I don't know whether it's because of the behind-login stuff or what is going on. As soon as I visit my route holding the component, my picks get rendered perfectly client-side, but on hard refresh, nothing is loaded server-side.
when I do the request server side, it seems that it tries to request just the "betting/picks" without baseUrl, so I guess that headers are not set as well, but don't know how to debug it.
I tried replacing my backend with a public json endpoint: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos, and that works out of the box server-side.
I've also tried disabling my authentication, so that my endpoint is public, but still no luck. So I really don't know what's going on??
So, hopefully some of you guys can help telling me, if what I want just can't be done or if I just am missing the greater picture of it??
Thanks a million!
